# Discord.js - Deleting role

Tags: discord.js

I want to delete role by pinging it in command "_drole @examplerole".
I tried getting it by `const role = message.mentions.roles.first();` and then tried to delete it with `role.delete()` but it is not working.

```js
if(command === "drole") { 
  if(message.member.roles.cache.has('726410974826856458') 
    || message.member.roles.cache.has('726517019788181515') 
    || message.member.roles.cache.has('726410166701916161')) { 
    const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
    role.delete(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Define _"not working"_ :)

Comment: It is saying that role is undefined.

Comment: So `message.mentions.roles.first()` returns `undefined`? Can you post your full code?

Comment: if(command === "drole") {
          if(message.member.roles.cache.has('726410974826856458') || message.member.roles.cache.has('726517019788181515') || message.member.roles.cache.has('726410166701916161')) {
            const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
            role.delete();
          }
        }

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me, if I mention a role, it deletes it. Are you sure you mention a role and not a member?

Comment: Yea i mentiond the role and it says that its undefined.